# Qt QImage shows wrong grayscale image

Tags: c++, qt, grayscale, qimage

I want to visualize a matrix of integer values between 0 and 255 as a gray-scale image in Qt 5.12. First, I built a sample 256x256 uchar array with values between 0 and 255 in each row. then I tried to show the image with QImage and format_grayscale as the format. But confusingly, the resulting image contains disturbed pixels in the last rows.

The Resulting Image

[image]

I also created a gray-scale color map and tried with format_indexed8, but the same result. Here is my code.

```
uchar imageArray[256][256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
    {
        imageArray[i][j] = uchar(j);
    }
}

QImage image(&imageArray[0][0],
                256,
                256,
                QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your buffer is deallocated and partially overwritten before you can get it displayed. It is your responsability to ensure the data buffer remains valid when using a constructor that does not perform a deep copy.

Quoting from [the Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-3):

> Constructs an image with the given width, height and format, that uses
>   an existing memory buffer, data. The width and height must be
>   specified in pixels. bytesPerLine specifies the number of bytes per
>   line (stride).
>
> The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all
>   copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the
>   original buffer. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction.
>   You can provide a function pointer cleanupFunction along with an extra
>   pointer cleanupInfo that will be called when the last copy is
>   destroyed.

Comment: I converted the matrix to static one and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a matrix but an array of size 256x256 = 65535 ,
So instead of :

```
uchar imageArray[256][256];
```

use :

```
uchar imageArray[65536];
```

Then fill your array with the values you want.
Then, call the constructor of QImage :

```
QImage image(imageArray, 256, 256, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

Comment: 256x256 = 65535? or 256x256 = 65536?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I have tried it and NO LUCK! (It showed the same result as defining 2d array)

Comment: Did you try both  Format_Grayscale8 and  Format_Indexed8 ?

Comment: Also, can you please post how you are filling your array ?

Comment: I tried both Format_Grayscale8 and Format_Indexed8. My code for Indexed8 is as follows. The matrix is filled with the loop mentioned in the code.